# Remove the back button text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Currently trying to remove the title of the previous VC on the back button. Following [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar) I have used:

```
let backBarButtton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtton
```

However the back button title does not disappear! The console says it's empty (""), but it's clearly still displayed to the user.

I do not want to use hacks such as setting the previous title of previous VC to "" however currently nothing else seems to be working. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function as `extension` of `UINavigationController` :

```
func setBackButtonTitle(_ title: String) {
    if self.navigationBar.topItem != nil {
        let leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backButtonAction))
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
    } else {
        if self.navigationBar.backItem != nil {
            self.navigationBar.backItem?.title = title
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't setting it on the top item! Thank you :)

Comment: Your welcome, kindly please upvote if you consider it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtton
```

Your code changes the appearance of back button when other controller pushed above current one. But You need to modify back button on current controller.

See docs on backBarButtonItem:

> When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the
>   stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the
>   navigation bar from this navigation item. When this property is nil,
>   the navigation item uses the value in its title property to create an
>   appropriate back button. If you want to specify a custom image or
>   title for the back button, you can assign a custom bar button item
>   (with your custom title or image) to this property instead. When
>   configuring your bar button item, do not assign a custom view to it;
>   the navigation item ignores custom views in the back bar button
>   anyway.

Answer (score 0):

u can init it with a UIButton instead

```
let button = UIButton()
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
```